# 2003 Honda CRV grinding noise from starter - possible flywheel damage?

Tags: honda, starter, crv, flywheel

I have a 2003 Honda CRV and my starter started skipping or slipping. It was making a horrible grinding sound, so I bought a new one and installed it only to have it do the same thing. The grinding sound is terrible, so is it possible the problem is the flywheel? Please help, they are very difficult to change out. Honda gave no room and placed it under the intake manifold.

Comment: Is this an automatic or manual transmission?

Comment: Did you see any evidence of damage to the pinion gear on the old starter?

Answer (score 2):

If the starter is the correct one and is fitted correctly then it sounds as if there are flats on the ring gear, this is a circular gear that is fitted to the flywheel. If the noise is as bad as you describe you could try pulling the starter out and looking into the hole where it fits, if you rotate the engine (by hand) you should easily be able to spot the parts on the ring gear that are worn. 
If the ring gear requires replacement then the gearbox has to be removed to do it.

Answer (score 1):

okay so it actually does answer the question , my own question because after buying another aftermarket starter only this time paying $180.00 more than the first one it fixed the problem, the less expensive one was around .150 shorter and the bendix also had a .150 less travel so this was the reason it would not engage.